# Maria DB JDBC Driver using too much CPU

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, mariadb

The Tomcat CPU Utilization on our Tomcat server is huge and upon using java visual vm, we are seeing considerable CPU utilization by Maria DB drivers. We are using Spring Boot and JPA in our applications.

[image: Java Visual VM]

Any ideas on what could be causing this, or how to dig this further and options to address this?

Answer (score 3):

This is the default behavior of mariadb / mysql connector, using socket.available() to retrieve all data from socket buffer. This is mainly if resultset contain huge data.

If CPU is important, this can be disabled using option `useReadAheadInput=false`. Connector will still be fast, just a little less for huge resultset.

I'm just wondering what environment do you use so socket.available does cost so much ?

Comment: I added the option as per your recommendation and as of now, I don't know the result yet. Both the Tomcat and Maria DB are on the same CentOS 7.X server. And the odd thing the app which does too many reads is used very little just a few hundred requests every day and also not used consistently. The other app deploy is supposed to write huge amounts of data and read very little data. So I am not sure if your recommendation will work, but I would still try to know the difference.

Comment: @kiran Your url for programsquare.com is not available today from here.